# How to place a guest order in case multi website using the Magento2 REST API?

Tags: php, magento2

I have two websites

1. UAE
2. KAS

If I place the order by using the guest cart, it's automatically assigned to store 1, which is a default for website 1: UAE.

There is no provision of creating quest cart specific to the website.
available website are:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "base",
    "name": "Main Website",
    "default_group_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "code": "admin",
    "name": "Admin",
    "default_group_id": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "saudiwebsite",
    "name": "Saudi Website",
    "default_group_id": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can place the order on respective site by using front-end URLs of the respective websites. The Magento API automatically places the order of the requested site.